# /usr/include folder missing in mac

Tags: python, xcode, macos, terminal

I've tried pretty much everything on stackoverflow and other forums to get the /usr/include/ folder on my mac (currently using OS X 10.9.5)

1. Re-installed Xcode and command line tools (actually, command line tool wasn't one of the downloads available - so I'm guessing it's was already downloaded)
2. tried /Applications/Install Xcode.app command line on terminal

I haven't tested if there is no standard library on Xcode, but I'm only trying to build cloudera/hue from github and it won't install because there is no /usr/include/python2.7 (and couldn't really ask their forum because the error isn't coming from cloudera/hue).

How do I get the /usr/include folder?

Comment: `sudo mkdir /usr/include`

Comment: is there a /usr/local/include?

Comment: Also have you installed python-dev or the mac equivalent?

Comment: @heinst that's obviously not the issue here :(

Comment: @Padraic there is no /usr/local/include, and I've installed python-devel and python 2.7 and all these..

Comment: can you run `locate include/python2.7`?

Answer (score 4):

Try on 10.14:

`sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`

Comment: This worked. `xcode-select --install` had already been run, but did not create the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
xcode-select --install
```